# Nginx Cache even if it's a 404 response

Tags: nginx, cache, http-status-code-404

I use 404 rewriting url:

```
    error_page 404 = /url_rewriting.php;
```

I cache images generated with a render script being in a folder /render/:

```
    set $no_cache 0;

    location ~ /render/ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            #fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

            fastcgi_buffers 8 16k; # increase the buffer size for PHP-FTP
            fastcgi_buffer_size 32k; # increase the buffer size for PHP-FTP
            fastcgi_cache_key $scheme$host$request_uri$request_method;
            fastcgi_cache PROD;
            fastcgi_cache_valid any 20d;
            fastcgi_cache_valid 404      1d;
            fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_503;
            fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
            fastcgi_hide_header "Set-Cookie";
            fastcgi_cache_bypass $no_cache;
            fastcgi_no_cache $no_cache;
            expires 10M;
            access_log off;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
            add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
    }
```

The cache works with an url like this:

```
https://mywebsite.com/include/php/render/framed/img.php?VR=1&size=300&image=U3pmwKi
```

But the cache does not work with an url like this:

```
https://mywebsite.io/include/php/render/framed/file/VR/1/size/300/image/U3dpwK
```

This second URL go through `error_page 404 = /url_rewriting.php;` because the directory 'file' does not exists but the script display the image thanks to url_rewriting.php script which do the trick

What do I have to update to my Nginx config to be able to cache 404 responses?

Answer (score 1):

Caching error responses is possible with the `always` keyword:

```
add_header Cache-Control "public; max-age=3600" always;
```

[From the docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header):

> Adds the specified field to a response header provided that the response code equals 200, 201 (1.3.10), 204, 206, 301, 302, 303, 304, 307 (1.1.16, 1.0.13), or 308 (1.13.0) ... **If the `always` parameter is specified (1.7.5), the header field will be added regardless of the response code.**

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure why but I needed to change the cache key.

`proxy_cache_key        "$host$request_uri";`

Full block:

```
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://gitlab-pages;
        include proxy_params;

        more_set_input_headers  "Host: templates.pages.example.com";

        proxy_cache            gitlab;
        proxy_cache_key        "$host$request_uri";
        proxy_cache_use_stale  error timeout updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504 http_404;
        proxy_cache_lock       on;
        proxy_cache_valid      200 302 304 404 5m;
        proxy_cache_valid      any 1m;
        proxy_cache_revalidate on;
        proxy_ignore_headers   "Set-Cookie";
        proxy_hide_header      "Set-Cookie";

        add_header            X-CACHE $upstream_cache_status always;
    }
```